# Can't get a Redirect Hook to Fire

Tags: 8, redirection

I'm attempting to use `hook_redirect_alter()` as described in `redirect.api.php`.

I created `my_module.module` and entered the hook as: `function my_module_redirect_alter($redirect)` To test I just entered a `drupal_set_message` and attempted to write a notice to the log but I can't seem to get it to actually fire.

```
function my_module_redirect_alter($redirect) {
  $message = "redirect_alter worked!";
    \Drupal::logger('my_module')->notice($message);
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? Am I misunderstanding this hook?

Comment: The hook is fired just before the redirect occurs, does that fit in with how you're testing it? So you'd need to add a redirect, then visit the original URL. You should be redirected to the new URL and the log message should be there in theory. If it's not check the usual (module is enabled, caches cleared, default logger is whatever logs you're checking), other than that it looks like it should work

Comment: @Clive Yep, that's what I'm trying to achieve. I'm need to allow published nodes to be redirected which currently isn't allowed in the redirect module. I'd restrict this from working on admin, /user, etc pages. I was hoping this hook would be able to help me to accomplish this.

Comment: @Clive Browsing through the issue queue it looks like some hooks have been deprecated: https://www.drupal.org/project/redirect/issues/2702391 Berdir mentions an alternative solution in #6.

Comment: @Vecta Hi, redirect maintainer here. Yes, those hooks are no longer called. I don't understand your use case but don't see how that hook could help with that. Maybe you're looking for a module like rabbithole instaed? Please explain what you're actually trying to do. The only thing that hook allowed to do in the past is customize a specific redirect (e.g. redirect from /a to /b) if that redirect matched the request already.

Answer (score 1):

Good afternoon.

1) install the devel module.

2) Install the modules, devel, kint.

3) change your code for the following:

```
function my_module_redirect_alter($redirect) {
   dpm($message = "redirect_alter worked!");
   kint($redirect);
}
```

4)  try to perform a process such as updating a node and when redirecting, you must show the messages.

**Note: dpm() and kint() are functions of the devel module to inspect a variable**